# Creating PHP class instance with a string

Tags: php

I have two classes, `class ClassOne { }` and `class ClassTwo {}`. I am getting a string which can be either `"One"` or `"Two"`.

Instead of using a long `switch` statement such as:

```
switch ($str) {
    case "One":
        return new ClassOne();
    case "Two":
        return new ClassTwo();
}
```

Is there a way I can create an instance using a string, i.e. `new Class("Class" . $str);`?

Answer (score 594, accepted):

Yes, you can!

```
$str = 'One';
$class = 'Class'.$str;
$object = new $class();
```

When using namespaces, supply the [fully qualified name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php):

```
$class = '\Foo\Bar\MyClass'; 
$instance = new $class();
```

You can also call variable functions & methods dynamically.

```
$func = 'my_function';
$parameters = ['param2', 'param2'];
$func(...$parameters); // calls my_function() with 2 parameters;

$method = 'doStuff';
$object = new MyClass();
$object->$method(); // calls the MyClass->doStuff() method. 
// or in one call
(new MyClass())->$method();
```

Also PHP can create [variables with a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as well, but it's a really bad practice that should be avoided whenever possible. Consider to use arrays instead.

Comment: FYI, you cannot partially use a variable. eg. ```$my_obj = Package\$class_name();```. Instead you have to ```$class_name = "Package\\" . $class_name; $my_obj = new $class_name();```

Comment: Please note the when using namespaces, you must supply the full path:
`$className = '\Foo\Bar\MyClass';`  
`$instance = new $className();`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with class names stored in constants. Anyone know more...?

Comment: There is no spoon...only php.

Comment: but one question. The method described above can be used to create a new class instance. What if I want to statically call a  method of an existing class ? I tried as follows: `$model = $user_model::find()->All(); ` where `$user_model` is the variable containing the string of the class being called

Comment: @RameshPareek Are you using namespaces? See the comment from Giel Berkers above.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with exceptions? Like could I pass an exception class into a function as a parameter and evaluate it in a try catch statement? (Without using eval())

Comment: Since we're dealing with strings, it's safer to escape the backslashes: `$className = '\\Foo\\Bar\\MyClass';` … right?

Comment: @RameshPareek Static calls can be made with `call_user_func` or string concatenation with parentheses. For example: `$model = ($user_model.'::find')()->All();`

Comment: @WoodrowSigeru Yes, single backslashes cause unexpected problems, as in `'\My\Namespace\' . $class` or `"\My\Namespace\{$class}"`, both of which are errors.

Comment: When using namespaces we must supply full qualified name. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Are there any security issue by using GET/POST params to instantiate a class? For example `new $_GET["class_name"]()`

Answer (score 29):

You can simply use the following syntax to create a new class (this is handy if you're creating a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)):

```
$className = $whatever;
$object = new $className;
```

As an (exceptionally crude) example factory method:

```
public function &factory($className) {

    require_once($className . '.php');
    if(class_exists($className)) return new $className;

    die('Cannot create new "' . $className . '" class - includes not found or class unavailable.');
}
```

Comment: Don't you miss a dot between the class name and the extension?`require_once($className.'php');`  -> `require_once($className.'.php');`

Answer (score 15):

have a look at example 3 from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

```
$className = 'Foo';
$instance = new $className(); // Foo()
```

Answer (score 10):

Lets say `ClassOne` is defined as:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    protected $arg1;
    protected $arg2;

    //Contructor
    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        $this->arg1 = $arg1;
        $this->arg2 = $arg2;
    }

    public function echoArgOne
    {
        echo $this->arg1;
    }

}
```

Using PHP Reflection;

```
$str = "One";
$className = "Class".$str;
$class = new \ReflectionClass($className);
```

Create a new Instance:

```
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs(["Banana", "Apple")]);
```

Call a method:

```
$instance->echoArgOne();
//prints "Banana"
```

Use a variable as a method:

```
$method = "echoArgOne";
$instance->$method();

//prints "Banana"
```

Using Reflection instead of just using the raw string to create an object gives you better control over your object and easier testability (PHPUnit relies heavily on Reflection)

Comment: Just for the curious, there is neglectable overhead in time for the using Reflection plus better control over exceptions like a missing class.

Answer (score 2):

```php
// Way #1
$className = "App\MyClass";
$instance = new $className();

// Way #2
$className = "App\MyClass";
$class = new \ReflectionClass($className);

// Create a new Instance without arguments:
$instance = $class->newInstance();

// Create a new Instance with arguments (need a contructor):
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs(["Banana", "Apple"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a namespace at the top of the file.

import the desired class at the top of the current file:

```
use \Foo\Bar\MyClass; 

// Assign the class namespace to a variable. 
$class = MyClass::class; 

// Create a new instance
$instance = new $class();
```

The `::class` will  return the entire namespace of the desired class