# Sending an object as a parameter in PHP, without instantiating it

Tags: php, class, object

How to send an object as paramater in a function call? I don't want to instantiate the object when passing it, so `myFunction( new myObject() )` wouldn't work.

I want `myFunction` to be able to instantiate the object later. I'm just not sure how to pass a class around in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a string and do:

```
myFunction($class) {
    $object = new $class();
}
```

But a better OOP approach would be to pass a factory object and let the factory create the object:

```
class MyFactory {
    public function create() { 
        return new myObject; 
    }
}

myFunction(MyFactory $factory) {
    $object = $factory->create();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the class name as a string, and instantiate it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578343/362536

```
function ($className) {
    $object = new $className();
}
```

Comment: Ah! I thought as much but I thought there may be another way without using strings. It works though. Good enough for me. Thank you.