# PHP OOP : Use string as identifier for an alias

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, aliases

I have a class somewhere in some namespace. Say:

```
namespace space;
class MyClass(){}
```

What i want to do is to create an alias for this class without extending etc. Oherenly thing I have is a string which contains class name. What I would like to do is:

```
$className='MyClass';
use '\space\'.$className as 'space_'.$classname;
```

Is it possible somehow? Because "use" keyword expects class identifier's literal string token (expecting identifier (T_STRING)) and usual approach, like with variables (say, call function named in a variable by simply calling $functionName()), as described, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string), doesn't help.

UPD: Using eval doesn't work for that, of course.

Comment: Sometimes, just sometimes, a very good case exist for dependency injection =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems you are looking for [class_alias](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php)

```
class_alias('space\MyClass', 'space_MyClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `class_alias` function.

```
 class_alias('space\\' . $className, 'space_' . $classname);
```

Or if you don't want to use this, you could also use a var like

```
$classname = 'space\\' . $className;
$class = new $classname()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace animal;

class Cats
{

    static function Says()
    {
        echo "This is working";
    }

}
$className = "Cats";

$classname = 'animal\\' . $className;
$class = new $classname();

echo $class->Says();


?>
```