# Error While instance a object from a String PHP

Tags: php, oop, object, instance, instance-variables

My problem is quite similar to this post: [a link][Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string) I want to instance an object from a String however my string came from a object property, I have this:

```
$type = strval($act->elementtype); $ty="Client";
$societe = new $type;
```

if I change `$societe = new $ty` it will work but no for `$societe = new $type` even when `$type` is equal to `Client` which is the name of my class. I recieve:

Fatal error: Class 'Client ' not found in....

Comment: Did you echo the $type variable ? Is so, and has the correct value then try the following. $societe = new {$type};

Comment: Looking at the error it seems there's an extra space after `Client`. Are you sure `$act-elementtype` doesn't contain some whitespace? Try using [trim](http://us2.php.net/trim).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, a couple hours later I found the solution (quite wear btw).

Answer (score 0):

It does't seem to be true that `$type` contains the same as `$ty`:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Client ' not found in....
                          ^
```

You can use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) to trouble-shoot this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. If someone needs the answer sometime, the think was the type of my variable in my BD `elementtype` was `type CHAR` so I try to change it in posgresql and set it `into CHAR VARYING` and it works!! Hope it help! ^^