# How to call a function with a parameter as string in php?

Tags: php, function, class

I am looking for something similar to the solution here >> [Call function from string stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable), however with one difference :

I would like to pass a parameter as well.

For example :

```
   function foo($myvar) {

   }


   $function = 'foo';
   $values = Array('myvar'=>1, 'myvar2'=>2);

   if(function_exists($function)) {
      // call the function using $function, 
      // and pass the value $values -- aka   $function($values)

   }
```

Any workable solution would be greatly appreciated.  Ideally, I would like to use it with classes as follows :

```
   class bar {

   function foo($myvar) {

   }

   }


   $function = 'foo';
   $values = Array('myvar'=>1, 'myvar2'=>2);

   if(function_exists($function)) {
      // call the function using $function, 
      // and pass the value $values -- aka   $bar::$function($values)

   }
```

Comment: I don't see where is the problem ? Can you give an example where it would cause a problem /

Comment: It's not a problem --- My question is how can i pass a variable to a function where the function name is stored in a variable.   Calling the function directly is not the issue.  If you look at the SO link i added, it gives an answer for how to call a function in a string, but not if i wish to pass a variable to that function as well. -- so it's only 50% of the solution i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a function on an object passing params, using variables, as follows:

```
$myBar = new bar(); // usually class names have uppercase first letters though
$myClassname = 'bar';
call_user_func(array($myBar, $function), $values); // method on object
call_user_func(array($myClassname, $function), $values); // class (static) method
call_user_func($myClassname.'::'.$function); // PHP 5.2.3 and higher
// if you had another function $function2 whose args were a list of parameters instead of an array:
call_user_func($myBar, $function2, $param1, $param2, $param3);
```

More info and examples at https://www.php.net/call_user_func

Comment: can the class itself be called this way as well ?   for example, in your example, the class is known and is static ---  but something like  `$foo = 'bar'; $mybar = new $foo;`  ?  or more specifically calling it statically like  `$foo::$myfunction($params)`   so all parts can be dynamic

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string

Comment: Awesome --- thank you :) -- lol... i have to wait to accept the answer XD

Comment: you're welcome! hope it helps. (ahh the things we'll do for an upvote or a green checkmark ;)

Comment: :) ...  I have a follow up question coming ... hehe... slightly more complex, but on topic with this -- basically, I am writing an event class (so I can raiseevents from other functions/classes/etc).  PHP doesn't seem to have any real event based system.

Comment: Just giving heads up... question is being written now.

Answer (score 1):

Does this helps ?

```
function process_function($function_param){
 $function_param = explode("|",$function_param);
   if(function_exists($function_param[0])) {
      call_user_func_array($function_param[0],$function_param[1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Also a good solution.  Allows for passing of the function name and one param.  RobP answered first and is a bit more thorough, however bump for decent solution anyway :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `method_exist()` which would check if object has particular method.

Here is your solution.

```
class bar {
   function foo($myarr){
        foreach($myarr as $val){
            echo $val ."<br />" ;
            //prints 1 and 2
        }
   }
}

$myfunc = new bar(); //creating object 
$values = Array('myvar'=>1, 'myvar2'=>2);

//checking object has method foo
if(method_exists($myfunc, 'foo')) {
    $myfunc->foo($values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ....  that is helpful as well.  I wish we could just combine all 3 answers into a single solution.  That doesn't really help with calling the function by string, but it does help with checking existence of function in a class.