# How to get class from string class name in Symfony

Tags: php, class, symfony

I need to access a const like this:

```
dump (Accomodation::MAX_IMAGES);
```

but I only have the string class name but not the class itself. For example, I have this string 'AppBundle:Accomodation' but I don't have the class `Accomodation` to access its static properties.

Any idea for Symfony?

Comment: Are you saying that the class Accomodation doesn't exist? If so in what circumstances are you trying to access an attribute of a class which doesn't exist? If I'm misunderstood, please clarify and add a little background info.

Comment: Sorry about my explanation... I have a string 'AppBundle:Accomodation' and I need the class Accomodation (already exists).

Comment: If you need to dump in an action method of a controller, then just import the respective class (Accomodation, in your case), by using `use AppBundle\Classes\Accomodation` (or whatever place you've created the Accomodation class), and it's enough to write it as you already did: `dump(Accomodation::MAX_IMAGES)`. That static property needs to be public accessible.

Comment: Yes, but the string 'AppBundle:Accomodation' may take several entity names, not just one, it is because of this I need to get the class itself

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "may take several entity names". Like you need to dump static properties from more than one entity class?

Comment: Yes... sometimes the string will be 'AppBundle:Accomodation' and others will be 'AppBundle:Room' or 'AppBundle:Company' or... etc so I can't import just Accomodation

Comment: @JesusM, _the string_ is a class name, right? Then maybe `AppBundle::Accomodation` (with double colon)?

Comment: I know how to use ReflectionClass but is there any way to get the class by a Symfony direct way?

Comment: If there are not hundreds of class names, I guess you need to import them all, then creating the dump as you already did. I really don't know if there is a way to dynamically import entities in a single `use` statement. Here, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29499194/4548751) might help you.

Comment: @JesusM, you have a class name and  a constant name. Then what could be easier than just `$class::C`, or `(new ReflectionClass($class))->getConstant($c)`? Do you need it be called "a part of Symfony"? Or do you think Symfony can do it better?

Comment: Wow! great! I've tried both solutions and both works. I take the way of Variable of variable @DanCostinel. Thanks to both for your time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the constant name is static, then access it directly:

```
echo $class_name::CONSTANT_NAME;
```

If, however, the constant name is a variable, use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstant.php):

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
echo $rc->getConstant($const_name);
```

**Example**

```
namespace MyNs;

class A {
  const C = 1;
}

$class_name = '\MyNs\A';
$c = 'C';

// method #1
echo $class_name::C, PHP_EOL;

// method #2
$rc = new \ReflectionClass($class_name);
echo $rc->getConstant('C'), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: What is the way to do a ReflectionClass in Symfony? not in php... thanks for your reply anyway!

Comment: @JesusM, Symfony is a PHP framework written in PHP. [Reflection is a part of PHP core](http://php.net/manual/en/reflection.installation.php), so you can use it freely in Symfony projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function as follow:

```
$constant = 'MAX_IMAGES';  
$className = Accomodation::class; // or AppBundle\Classes\Accomodation
$classWithConstant = sprintf('%s::%s', $className, $constant);
dump(constant($classWithConstant));
```

Hope this help