# Class not found when creating a class with class name being a string

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error

I need to create classes based on the parameter passed to a function. I do it this way:

```
public function index($source)
    {
        if(in_array($source, ModuleManager::getAllModules()))
        {
            $provider = new $source();
            if($image)
            {
                return $provider->getAll(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return $provider->getAll(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that on line 5 I'm trying to create an object of class `$source` which will definitely be available. I understand that the above code is actually an `eval` call. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and the above code returns:

```
FatalThrowableError in ProcReqController.php line 19:
Fatal error: Class 'Example' not found
```

In the above error `Example` can be any class that I made. Now if I hard code the value of `$source` then it works just fine.

What am I getting that error?

Comment: Does class `Example` have a namespace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what's happening is PHP gets confused when you try to instantiate a class whose class name is in a variable and it has to do with imports.

### Solution 1

Set your `$class` variable to the fully qualified class name including the namespace and it should work.

In this way, `new $class()` should work even while including parenthesis.

### Solution 2

After further testing, it seems when you instantiate a variable class, it always assumes global namespace.

With this in mind, you can use `class_alias` to alias each of your classes.  In `config/app.php`, you can add each class to the `aliases` array.

```
'aliases' => [
    ....

    'Example' => App\Example::class
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The autoloader allows you to use classes without fully qualifying them... in the php interactive shell you'll have to manually include classes AND fully qualify them.

if you have a composer project, go to it's directory and do the following to load the Primal color classes:

```
    set_include_path(getcwd().'/vendor/primal/color/lib/Primal/Color/');
    include 'Color.php';
    include 'Parser.php';
    include 'RGBColor.php';
    include 'HSVColor.php';
    $hello = Primal\Color\Parser::parse('#666');
    var_export($hello->toHSV());

/*
returns
Primal\Color\HSVColor::__set_state(array(
   'hue' => 0,
   'saturation' => 0,
   'value' => 37.647058823529413,
   'alpha' => 1,
))
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the parentheses at the end of the instantiation call, I think.

Check out this php interactive shell session:

```
php > class Foo { };
php > $fooname = 'Foo';
php > $bar = new $fooname;
php > var_dump($bar);
object(Foo)#2 (0) {
}
```

src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578350/2694851

Comment: Removing parentheses doesn't help.