# Laravel 5.1: Calling a function from string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Currently I'm trying to call a function from a string.

This is the function, that I'll call later:

```
<?php
namespace App\Validation\Options;

class FacebookOptionValidation
{
    static public function validate()
    {
       echo: 'example';
       die();
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Profile;

use App\Validation\Options;

class ProfileUserEditController extends Controller {

    public function updateUserOption()
    {
        $class = 'Options\FacebookOptionValidation';

        $class::validate();
    }
}
```

In this case Laravel shows an error:
**Class 'Options\FacebookOptionValidation' not found**

But when I call my function like this, everything works fine:

```
use App\Validation\Options;

class ProfileUserEditController extends Controller {

    public function updateUserOption()
    {
        Options\FacebookOptionValidation::validate();
    }
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string), it's possible to call a class/function from a string. But in my case it's not possible - neither in the static or non-static variant.

Is that a 'laravel-thing'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try call with full namespace

```
    class ProfileUserEditController extends Controller {

        public function updateUserOption()
        {
            $class = 'App\Validation\Options\FacebookOptionValidation';

            $class::validate();


         }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you!

Can you explain me based on my exmaple, why Options\FacebookOptionValidation::validate(); works fine, while my string variant has problems?

Comment: @FlorianLauterbach  I think when php interprets the file it appends namespaces to a class name. But when you trying to call like string, php thinks it's just a string and doesn't append namespace. It's just an opinion and I could mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

With PHP7 you can even do this:

```
(App\Validation\Options\FacebookOptionValidation::class)::validate();
```

One line of code and without using a string

Comment: Thanks for the mention. However, at this point the string is needed because I develop a flexible system which is manageable through an ACP :)

Comment: @FlorianLauterbach : ok. Maybe it cloud be useful for other readers :)