# PHP - Getting an array of instantiated objects having an array of classes

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

My question is what is a neat way to obtain an array of objects from an array of classes.

The array of classes I get by using `array_filter()` on `get_declared_classes()`.

EDIT:

My own attempts were pretty correct, the thing was I forgot to return value of `in_array()` in callback function :

```
$classes_array = array_filter(
     get_declared_classes(),
        function($class_name){
           return in_array('IItem', class_implements($class_name));
         }

$objects_array;
    foreach($classes_array as $class){
        $objects_array[] = new $class();
    }
```

Comment: Not event an example to work off of?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: This may helps, [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578343/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map()`, and refer to [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578335/6521116)

```
$objects = array_map(function($v){
  return new $v();
}, get_declared_classes());
```

Comment: This answer is correct, thank you very much! But in fact it is analogous to my own attempts, so it pointed me to that something else is wrong with my code than instantiating object by `new $class()` as I thought before. It turned out that I just forgot to return the value of `in_array()`.