# need to convert string namespace to stdclass

Tags: php, stdclass

I am using this name space

```
use \App\Model\PostsModel;
```

and i am trying to access the class like this in another class :

```
public $model = PostsModel::class;
```

the out put of `vardump` is   "App\Model\PostsModel"  and `vardump` shows that the type of it is string.

I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find how to cast/convert string into stdclass. This is what I have tried:

```
$model = \App\Model\PostsModel;
```

I also tried to get a instance of it

```
public $model = new \App\Model\PostsModel;  
public $model = new PostsModel::class;
```

My vardump is:

```
vardump($this->model);
```

which shows that my namespace addresses are correct

Comment: remove the slaces(/) from your namespace `use App\Model\PostsModel ;`

Comment: i still get the same error -->  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSelect() on string

Comment: Please provide minimal reproduce - code what you are using, errors you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access the class without instantiating before.

The value from `ClassName::class`is always a string, not an instance of that class.

You can assign the class name (string) to a var and then create a new instance of the class just using that variable. See the next example.

```
<?php

use \App\Model\PostsModel;

class OtherClass {
    public $model;

    public function callOther() {
        $this->model = PostsModel::class;

        $instance = new $this->model();
        $instance->callSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ,my problem solved with the way you said , but i had tried $this->model = new PostsModel::class ; why this way doesn't work ? aren't these same thing ?

Comment: @ImanEmadi as i said the problem is `ClassName::class` or in this case `PostsModel` is returning the namespace and name of the class as string. The best way to create a new class instance is calling directly without the class. `$this->model = new PostsModel();` See the example 3 in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Look this question/answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string