# Why dont create Object so?

Tags: php, class, yii2, declaration

Before I could create an object in this way in PHP:

```
 use myFolder\models\Document;
 $nameClass = 'Document';
 $model = new $nameClass;
```

This used to work without problems.

But now it gives me a error

Is it for the PHP version or configuration?
What is the problem?

Why it sentence works fine?

```
$model = new Document;
```

and the previous one fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string)

Comment: Does Document have a namespace?

Comment: It should work. Please specify the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
The problem was the namespace; it should have been

```
use myFolder\models\Document;
$nameClass = 'myFolder\models\Document';
$model = new $nameClass;
```