# How to create new php objects within a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I've got an array with some php class names (e.g. ClassOne.php)

```php
classes = [ 'ClassOne' ,  'ClassTwo' ,  'ClassTree' ];
```

I want to write a loop that creates a new object for each of the class names. Without a loop, it looks like this:

```php
$class1 = new ClassOne;
$class2 = new ClassTwo;
$class3 = new ClassTree;
```

After that object creation I want to check if $class1,2,3, ... is a instance of the main class (Components)

Is it possible to store the new objects in a array that can get iterated like this?

```php
    $classes = [ $classs1, $class2, $class3 ];
    foreach($classes as $class)
    {
        if (is_object($class) && $class instanceof Component)
        {
             echo 'is an instance of Components';
        }
    }
```

Comment: So do these 3 classes actually exist? Like do you have a `Class ClassOne {}` etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes they allready exist. Now I want to proof if the class names in the array are instances of the class components

Comment: Tidied up the wording and code formating to improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do simple loop as:

```
foreach($phpclasses as $class) {
    $classes[] = new $class();
}
```

Or you can cobine your loop and do:

```
foreach($phpclasses as $class) {
    $c = new $class();
    if (is_object($c) && $cinstanceof Component)
        echo 'is an instance of Components';
}
```

Can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string) question also

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I there a opportunity to do this also for classes with a constructor? So if something is needed to create a new object of a class

Comment: @phpprogrammerhelp312 Sure - see how it works with constructor here: https://3v4l.org/stjco