# in php is there any way for geting type of class from string? and not intance of it

Tags: php, laravel

my target is like something this:

```
$s = 'myclass';
$s::my_methode()
...
```

this link is good but not my answer: [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string)

Comment: this not work for me:         
        call_user_func(array($class_name, 'create'));
        call_user_func($class_name .'::create($request->all())'); // >5.2.3

Comment: define "does not work". At least show the error you are getting

Comment: when class name is "App\Model\Company":Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::create($request->all())()

when class name is "Company": call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Company' not found

Comment: this not work too: call_user_func($class_name .'::create('.$request->all().')'); __
error is: Array to string conversion

Comment: What about `call_user_func([$class_name, 'create'], $request->all());`?

Comment: call_user_func([$class_name, 'create'], $request->all()); work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to call a class method by string if you know enough about [Callables](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/language.types.callable.php). The below code requires PHP 7.0+

```php
<?php

class A {
        public static function hello($target) {
                echo 'hello ' . $target . "\n";
        }
}

// call class "A" method 'hello'
$name = 'A';
[$name, 'hello']('world');
```

Result:

```
hello world
```

Please note that `$name` should be the full namespace name for the class (even if it is called within proper namespace). So if the full class name is `App\Model\Company`, the `$name` variable should contain `"App\Model\Company"`, not `"Company"`.