# How to change oracle rightnow namespaces object name dynamically using php

Tags: php, rightnow-crm

Here we have a code like this

```
$cm=RNCPHP\HRIA\Contact_WaitList::getMetadata();
```

i want to change namespace values dynamically like to

```
$cm= RNCPHP\HRIA\{$dynamicvalue}::getMetadata();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, but you may want to try the `str_replace()` function and replace '=' with '= ' (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string)

Comment: @Nathanael is correct. You are asking a PHP question, not a Service Cloud question. Use `str_replace` or `sprintf` to dynamically assign which namespace and class you are attempting to access in your PHP script.

As a side question, what are you doing in your script that would warrant this approach? Likely you do not need to do this while using the Connect for PHP APIs leveraging best practices.