# Using variable with string for new class initialization

Tags: php, class, phalcon

I need to initialize new class Safe with constructor call.

The way it works:

```
$paymentPortal = new Safe($order);
```

The way it doesnt:

```
$portal = 'Safe';
$paymentPortal = new $portal($order);
```

I get error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Safe' not found in ...
```

Is there a way to dynamically call class initialization?
If it is important, I'm using Phalcon framework..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating PHP class instance with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578335/creating-php-class-instance-with-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using string based creation, you must use the fully qualified namespace of the class regardless of the local namespace.

```
use My\Stuff;
$o = new Stuff();
$name = ‘My\Stuff’;
$o = new $name();
$name = Stuff::class;
$o = new $name();
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I was missing namespace. After concatenating it in front, it started working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about the namespace? if you are using an IDE it may have deleted the namespace. Check that.

Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, thought about that, and I did check it twice. Was using working solution at first but then realized it would be nice to have it a bit more dynamic, changed to variable name and namespace use remained, IDE didn't remove it.